# Using a negative margin, how do I overlap a div and hide it?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get one div to overlap another and hide the text behind. Even if I specify a background colour or image, the text shows through.

http://www.purple-mouse.co.uk/overlapdiv.php

I'd like the second div to hide the first one.

I'm using a negative margin as my CMS uses a repeating region and I need the second div to push the remaining sections down.

Thanks

Mandy

Comment: if you want to hide that div. Then why are you using it?

Comment: why dont use display:none ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `position:relative` for Top text DIV.

Below is the `CSS`:

```
element.style {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFF00;
    margin-top: -38px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bottom">
            Bottom text
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="top"> Top text </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.bottom {
  z-index: 1; 
  position: relative; 
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% white;
}
.top{
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% yellow; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 0; 
  margin-top: -32px;
}
```

with `z-index` and `position: relative`